# How to insert data via seeding Laravel 5.7 into two relation tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

When I want to execute command php artisan db:seed in terminal, I insert exactly the same number of rows to table one table (Posts table), from seed file(PostSeed). For example, 3 rows.

Also, I defined 6 rows to insert 6 rows to another table (Client table) from seed file(ClientSeed).

The problem called, after I executed command php artisan db:seed, I have 9 rows in table Clients. The table Posts are good, but table Client some how add 3 rows more.

This is my link of code https://github.com/mihnikola/laravel.git

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `PostFactory` is also creating a new `Client`.

```
'client_id' => function () {
    return factory(App\Client::class)->create()->id; // <- This will create a new client
}
```

So 3 posts will be created with 3 clients.

6 + 3 = 9

Comment: I see no reason in deleting the extra clients after your seed since you are seeding fake data. However you might have something else in mind. What would be the reason for you to only have 6 clients?

Comment: Thank Thomas Van der Veen.

Comment: I want to have 6 clients and 10 posts. But I don't have a clue, how to do that.

Comment: I find out a way. I change something to PostFactory.